# C#: How to use unrar.dll & unrar.cs from rarlab to extract a split archive?

Tags: c#, rar, unrar

I've downloaded the [unrar.dll for Windows software developers](https://www.rarlab.com/rar/UnRARDLL.exe) from [rarlab.com](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm), included the unrar.dll and the class of unrar.cs into my C# WPF project.

It extracts single archives (even with password set):

```
string source = "d:\\unrartest\\compressed\\myarchive.part1.rar";
string dest = "d:\\unrartest\\extracted";
Unrar unrar = new Unrar();
unrar.Password = "password_of_myarchive";
unrar.Open(@source, Unrar.OpenMode.Extract);
while (unrar.ReadHeader())
{
    unrar.ExtractToDirectory(@dest);
}
unrar.Close();
```

... but not split ones:

```
System.IO.IOException: "File CRC Error"
```

As there is no documentation around, I would like to know

1. how to handle `unrar.ReadHeader()` to proceed with the next
   file of a split archive
2. how to determine the first file of a split archive, in general
3. (optional) how to determine the progress of the overall extraction
   process (to output the progress in my program during runtime)

Comment: I have never used this library before, but I would assume it is not possible, as I doubt it understands what is in the compressed file. I'm guessing you need to check for other archives in the destination directory and then extract these too.

Comment: I guess, you meant "for other archive files in the **source** directory". I am able to determine all archive files in a list ("arch.part1.rar", "arch.part2.rar", ...) and let's assume, one can determine the first file of a multiple archive simply by sorting the files by name. So, I would start with "arch.part1.rar" like shown in the code. How can I proceed with the next one ("arch.part2.rar" and so on until it reached the last file)?

Comment: Apologies I think I mis-read. To get all the files in the directory you can do var archiveList = Directory.GetFiles("d:\\unrartest\\compressed\\", "*.rar").ToList(); and the loop through this, is this what you're after?

Comment: No. A loop would be sufficient if every .rar-file would be a single archive - but I want to handle a single multiple archive (means an archive with multiple .rar-files). So, I somehow need to inform the actual single extraction process of the unrar class (which uses the unrar.dll) to proceed with the next file of the archive it actually processes.

Comment: How about using a better, open-source library like https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/ or many others. Examples are included in the readme. Multi-part files should be supported normally.

Comment: @Viezevingertjes Besides not knowing how to include this library it looks a bit overloaded. Has nobody yet used unrar.dll directly for split files?

Comment: I think most people prefer a native library instead of interop of a C++ assembly (which you most of the time, would like to avoid), so that might be the reason why there is little to find about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The c# wrapper and example included in the unrardll is outdated and does not work well with multivolume rar files because there are new callback messaged that are not handled. To fix it change:

```
private enum CallbackMessages : uint
{
    VolumeChange = 0,
    ProcessData = 1,
    NeedPassword = 2
}
```

to

```
private enum CallbackMessages : uint
{
    VolumeChange=0,
    ProcessData=1,
    NeedPassword=2,
    VolumeChangeW = 3,
    NeedPasswordW = 4,
}
```

And handle the new callback message for VolumeChangeW:

```
private int RARCallback(uint msg, int UserData, IntPtr p1, int p2)
{
    string volume=string.Empty;
    string newVolume=string.Empty;
    int result=-1;

    switch((CallbackMessages)msg)
    {
        case CallbackMessages.VolumeChange:
        case CallbackMessages.VolumeChangeW:

            if ((CallbackMessages)msg == CallbackMessages.VolumeChange)
                volume =Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p1);
            else
                volume = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(p1);

            if ((VolumeMessage)p2==VolumeMessage.Notify)
                result=OnNewVolume(volume);
            else if((VolumeMessage)p2==VolumeMessage.Ask)
            {
                newVolume=OnMissingVolume(volume);
                if(newVolume.Length==0)
                    result=-1;
                else
                {
                    if(newVolume!=volume)
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i<newVolume.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Marshal.WriteByte(p1, i, (byte)newVolume[i]);
                        }
                        Marshal.WriteByte(p1, newVolume.Length, (byte)0);
                    }
                    result=1;
                }
            }
            break;

        case CallbackMessages.ProcessData:
            result=OnDataAvailable(p1, p2);
            break;

        case CallbackMessages.NeedPassword:
            result=OnPasswordRequired(p1, p2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that works! Awesome solution. I too was facing issues and was right about executing rar.exe in a shell. But now I'm able to use unrar.dll which is a way more clean approach!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue hoping for an answer to all my problems. But I just found my solution and am willing to share.

> 1. how to handle unrar.ReadHeader() to proceed with the next file of a split archive

If you are using the C# example from Unrar, you should remove the `IOException("File CRC Error")` in `ProcessFileError()` or throw the error. Same thing for File Open Error if you opened in read mode.
if `continuedOnNext == false`.

```c#
case RARError.BadData:
    if (!currentFile.continuedOnNext) throw new IOException("File CRC Error");
    else break;
```

The next file will be the exact same filename and will extract successfully (assuming the file in part 2 isn't corrupted). Do note that if you list the new files, you need to modify this statement in `ReadHeader()`:

```cs
// Determine if new file
if (((header.Flags & 0x01) != 0) && currentFile != null)
        currentFile.ContinuedFromPrevious = true;
```

To this:

```cs
// Determine if new file
if ((header.Flags & 0x01) != 0) return true;
```

You want to return true if you don't want to stop a while read loop.

> how to determine the first file of a split archive, in general

If you mean how to determine if the archive is the first volume, you should change the private property in Unrar.cs, `archiveFlags`, to a more accessible modifier (ex: internal or public).

To check if it's a volume/split archive:

```cs
bool isVolume = (RARObj.archiveFlags & RAR.ArchiveFlags.Volume) == RAR.ArchiveFlags.Volume
```

To check if it's the first volume/split archive:

```cs
bool isFirstVolume = (RARObj.archiveFlags & RAR.ArchiveFlags.FirstVolume) == RAR.ArchiveFlags.FirstVolume
```

> how to determine the progress of the overall extraction process (to output the progress in my program during runtime)

You can use `ListFiles` to get the archive file count and use that as the main archive extraction process. Then extract and create an event for `RARObj.ExtractionProgress` to update whatever ProgressBar you have.

`ExtractionProgressEventArgs e` has the property `PercentComplete` for you to update your progress bar. I suggest you analyze how the WinRAR app does it so you can get a better idea of how this works.

oh one more thing.

```cs
RAR RARObj = new Unrar(archive.path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Basically, it works with [SharpCompress](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/) as suggested by @Viezevingertjes in the comments above. But unfortunately, SharpCompress does not yet support RAR5 decryption, which means that RAR5 password protected files are not extracted, at all and therefore SharpCompress has a limited usage.

As workaround, you can only use rar.exe, unrar.exe or winrar.exe directly by a process call like this:

```
string rarExec = "\"c:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\Rar.exe\"";
string sourceRar = "\"c:\\sourceFolder\\myfile.part001.rar\"";
string targetPath = "\"c:\\destinationFolder\"";
string password = "topsecret";

using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = rarExec;
    if (password != "")
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c x -cfg- -inul -y " + "-p" + password + sourceRar + " " + targetPath;
    else
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c x -cfg- -inul -y " + sourceRar + " " + targetPath;

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    switch (process.ExitCode)
    {
        case 0:
            // "OK: extracted";
            break;
        case 10:
            // "Error: wrong password";
            break;
        default:
            // "Error: unknown";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would actually love a dll call instead of doing the `exe` way!